# Create XML from Sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, database, sqlxml

How to create XML in below format from SQL Query in SQL Server?

```
<ROOT><ELEMENT>VALUE1</ELEMENT></ROOT>
<ROOT><ELEMENT>VALUE2</ELEMENT></ROOT>
<ROOT><ELEMENT>VALUE3</ELEMENT></ROOT>
```

Comment: Show your query and result

Comment: The **root**-node is the one (and only!) outer-most element. There is no rule that it must be named `<root>`, nor is there a rule, that nodes **within** the XML should not be named as such. But it is - at least - very unusual... The multiple `<ROOT>` nodes could mean, that you need several independant XMLs... If the existing answers do not solve your issue, please poste some sample data and the expected output, together with some details about your goal. And - last but not least - show what you've tried already...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it something like:

```
select T.Element as 'Element'
from 
(
    select 'VALUE1' as Element
    union all 
    select 'VALUE2'
    union all 
    select 'VALUE3'
) as T
for xml path('ROOT')
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Derived table is not necessary

Comment: @Prdp well, it is just "ready-to-use" snippet  and subquery is just emulation of source table.

Comment: got the solution SELECT ROW.ELEMENT AS ELEMENT FROM table_name ROW FOR XML AUTO,elements

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT t.value AS ELEMENT          
     FROM [dbo].tbl t
     FOR XML PATH ('ROOT');
```